# MPlayer cannot fullscreen in Debian Jessie (Radeon R7 M265)

Tags: debian, radeon, acer

MPlayer cannot do full screen in my freshly installed Debian Jessie on Ace Aspire E5-551G-T16Q laptop that has AMD Radeon R7 series graphics. Here is the output from `lshw -short -C display`:

```
H/W path         Device      Class          Description
=======================================================
/0/100/1                     display        Kaveri [Radeon R6 Graphics]
/0/100/2.1/0                 display        Opal XT [Radeon R7 M265]
```

While it is possible to play video files in `mplayer`, it is not possible to see fullscreen. Here are the possibly interesting lines of `mplayer` output during startup:

```
Failed to open VDPAU backend libvdpau_nvidia.so: cannot open shared object file:
No such file or directory
[vdpau] Error when calling vdp_device_create_x11: 1
[VO_XV] It seems there is no Xvideo support for your video card available.
[VO_XV] Run 'xvinfo' to verify its Xv support and read

[VO_XV] DOCS/HTML/en/video.html#xv!
[VO_XV] See 'mplayer -vo help' for other (non-xv) video out drivers.
[VO_XV] Try -vo x11.
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
[gl] GLX version older than 1.3.
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
[gl] no GLX support present
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
```

Debian Jessie installation was pretty straightforward. I did not perform any `Xorg` config and do not have `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`. Installing `nvidia-vdpau-driver` that brings `libvdpau_nvidia.so` (in the error above) does not help. Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Output from `dpkg -l | grep glx`:

```
ii  libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64                 10.3.2-1+deb8u1                      amd64        free implementation of the OpenGL API -- GLX runtime
ii  libxcb-glx0:amd64                     1.10-3+b1                            amd64        X C Binding, glx extension
```

I just reinstalled Debian and continue to face the same problem making me believe that it is not due to something that I've done.

Comment: What GLX packages do you have installed? `dpkg -l | grep glx` to start with, perhaps.

Answer (score 1):

I have been able to get `mplayer` to play in full screen by installing proprietary drivers gtom AMD as per instructions: [here](https://wiki.debian.org/ATIProprietary).

I had tried this earlier having installed Jessie for the first time but had to undo the step after rebooting to a non-GUI screen (textual login screen only). I reckon this was due to installing the `nvidia-vdpau-driver` package that apparently breaks the sanity of the system. Hope this saves the time of others.

EDIT: Even if one does not wish to use `mplayer` there is noticeable screen
flicker while scrolling web pages when the [open source driver](https://wiki.debian.org/AtiHowTo) is used. So, the proprietary driver might have to be used anyway.